# PvZ2 Endless Zone Glitch

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

In plants vs zombies 2, sometimes after I beat a level in endless zone, it takes me straight to the next round without letting me pick a new plant. If I try to retire, it takes me back to endless zone again. When I finally lose, it says my high score is whatever round I was at when the glitch started.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a glitch from the last update.  Everyone is experiencing it.  Go to the google play store and read the comments. EA needs to fix it and do another update.

Answer (score 0):

This glitch can occasionally occur where players can't quit Endless Zone. When attempting to quit, the game returns the player to the plant selection screen. This glitch also causes the card selection page to be skipped. It is similar to the Zen Garden glitch, since it changes the zombies that appear. To fix it, quit the app from the plant selection page (where you would "retire" from Endless).

I copied this from the wiki. Gonna try it out myself. Thought this might help you.

Comment: http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Plants_vs._Zombies_2:_It's_About_Time/Glitches